# Django-templated-email does not send email

Tags: django, email

I am using the following package https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-templated-email in a Django app to try and send an email. I am running it inside a django management command.

When I run the command the email part outputs to the console but no email is actually sent out. The SMTP settings and such are correct as emails work fine for other areas of the application.

```
from templated_email import send_templated_mail

send_templated_mail(
    template_name='welcome',
    from_email='from@example.com',
    recipient_list=['to@example.com'],
    context={
        'username':"test",
        'full_name':"test",
        'signup_date':"test"
    },
)
```

Any help is appreciated. I suspect I have misunderstood the syntax of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Signup_date must be date and username and full_name must use single quote

Comment: these are just context I am passing for testing